Решение уравнения с неизвестной константой
Есть нелинейное уравнение с переменной x и неизвестной константой S. Известно, что S > 0. Необходимо найти корни x, выраженные с помощью S.
Пример:
x^2 - S = 0
x1 = √S
x2 = -√S

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть какие библиотеки для NodeJS, которые помогут решить данную задачу?
Изначально пробовал решать при помощи средств из Численных методов, но с их помощью не решить уравнение с константой.

Ничего не понятно...

сомневаюсь, что в node.js есть хоть что-то связанное с математикой. тем более символьные вычисления. я бы смотрел в сторону mathlab, если хочется чтоб было консольное приложение, то смотреть в сторону python, например такой модуль

@Qwertiy Похоже, человеку нужен микро-Wolfram...

https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/algebra.html - оно?

@chorkov, не совсем. При помощи mathjs не получилось это сделать, т.к. у меня переменная и константа, и решить уравнение при помощи неизвестной константы mathjs не смог.

Задача в принципе неразрешима.
Возьмём уравнение: X^5 - X - S = 0
Это уравнение подходит под условие вашей задачи, и даже похоже на приведённый пример, но увы, для него в принципе невозможно написать решение в виде формулы. Это уравнение пятой степени неразрешимо в радикалах, то есть нет формулы, которая выражает корни уравнения через коэффициенты.
ИМХО, тот, кто задал вам эту задачу, изрядно над вами поглумился.
